# Unexplained ValueError("No tables found") occurring using Python pandas.read_html

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, python-requests, stringio

**Problem:** An unexplained `ValueError("No tables found")` is being raised intermittently when using pandas `read_html` in conjunction with a proxy-configuration to parse data from multiple webpages (Python 3.x).

---

**Background:** To access each webpage, `http_url` is used as the target address. After each iteration of the loop, the `{team}` parameter in `http_url` is updated to access the next webpage (*32 total pages – same host domain*):

```py
for team in teams:
    http_url = f"http://www.footballguys.com/stats/game-logs-against/teams?team={team}&year={season_year}"
```

---

**Problem Description:** The target data from each webpage (`http_url`) is retrieved/parsed into a list of pandas DataFrames using the `read_html` method in one of two ways:

1. **Without Using a Proxy –** The HTML is parsed directly from each webpage:

```py
dataframe_list = pd.read_html(http_url)
```

> **Successful:** This method *always* successfully returns the list of `DataFrames` from each webpage – loop completes after returning data from all 32 webpages.

2. **Using a Proxy:** The the HTML is parsed from the returned unicode `GET` response converted to a string/file-like object using `io.StringIO`:

```py
proxies = {
            "http": "http://{}:{}@{}:{}".format(proxy_user, proxy_pass, proxy_host, proxy_port)
        }
```

> The `proxies` dict is configured by concatenating `proxy_user`, `proxy_pass`, `proxy_host`, `proxy_port`, which are input strings for each proxy parameter of the same name, and passed to the `=proxies` argument in each `GET` request.

```py
source = requests.get(http_url, proxies=proxies, verify=False).text
dataframe_list = pd.read_html(io.StringIO(source))
```

> **Frequently Unsuccessful:** This method *frequently*, and without explanation, returns `ValueError("No tables found")`. This error may be raised after the 2nd `GET` request or the 29th, there is seemingly no pattern.

---

**Additional Details:**
The results of five consecutive run-tests using the *Option 2 - Proxy Method* including the inspected response details from any returned failed requests:

| # Successful Requests Before `ValueError` | Details of Failed Response |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | `MAX_THREADS_REACHED` |
| 21 | Request failed from proxy-provider:`Request failed. You will not be charged for this request...` |
| 13 | `http.client.RemoteDisconnected:...` During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: `urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError:...` During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: `requests.exceptions.ProxyError:...` **Note:** Error messages should be posted in full, but I haven't done so as this is not a `ValueError`. I've noted it incase it *would* be helpful to see the full error, but I thought it might be excessive to post right away, for what looks to be a blocked request (*even though being blocked would be strange since the residential proxy-provider uses custom headers*). |
| 14 | `MAX_THREADS_REACHED` |
| All requests successful | - |

**Edit -** I find/found the `MAX_THREADS_REACHED` response to be the most perplexing, therefore, I reached out to my residential proxy-provider and, unfortunately, they confirmed that that response was not being returned from their API. I had hoped they might provide some insight, as I have not been able to find any documentation with those specific response details, and I am stumped as to what could possibly be causing that error. For reference, my program is not multi-threaded & the proxy allows up to 5 concurrent requests, which I am not surpassing.

Comment: Have you inspected the response details for the proxy request when you get the `ValueError`?

Comment: @acurtis166 I've updated the question to include the response details for five run-tests